# How to list elements maintaining order and reverse iteration?

Tags: java, data-structures, collections, linked-list

What is the best list/set/array in Java that combines the following aspects:

- maintain order of added elements
- make if possible to both iterate forwards and backwards
- of course good performance

I thought about a LinkedList, I then could insert elements by `add(0, element)` which would simulate a reverse order. Most of the time I will be using backwards iteration, so using this I can just iterate trough.
And if not, I can `list.listIterator().hasPrevious()`.

But are there better approaches?

Comment: Do you ever add or remove elements? If do you, you might want to say a few words about whether the new/deleted elements are at the front, back or are in the middle. Also, do you need to access elements by index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ArrayList` is an efficient, commonly used list data structure in Java, and is typically the mutable list type used most frequently in Java programs.  Unless you need functionality provided by a more specific list type, or are creating a fixed immutable list (in which case the [`List.of`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#of(java.lang.Object%5B%5D)) methods would likely be better), I'd recommend `ArrayList`.

As of Java 21, a reversed view of any `List` can be obtained using that object's [`reversed`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#reversed()) method.  This can be used to iterate through the list backwards.

```java
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(List.of(1, 2, 3));

list.forEach(e -> System.out::println); // Forwards iteration
list.reversed().forEach(e -> System.out::println); // Backwards iteration
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can get by index and wish to iterate over the collection then you can use a `List` and `get(index)` allow you to get the object in that place in the list. Arrays allow you to do this, you can just reference the index as normal, however if your array might grow then a Collection is going to be easier to use.

You can use `List.size()` and element through the object using a `for` loop rather than using an `Iterator` object, this will allow you to iterator over the list both forwards and backwards. For example:

```
List<AnObject> myList = new ArrayList<AnObject>;
// Add things to the list

for (int i = 0 ; i < myList.size; i++) {
  AnObject myObject = myList.get(i);
} 

for (int i = myList.size()-1 ; i <= 0 ; i--) {
  AnObject myObject = myList.get(i);
}
```

Set is not applicable as a Set does not maintain ordering.

Comment: Does ArrayList maintain the order of elements how they are inserted? I thought it would not...

Comment: The ordering of elements depends on how they are inserted, you can put them in any order and insert elements at any location in the List. Once objects have been inserted though as long as no elements are added / removed the ordering will stay the same. This is in the List contract itself (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html).

Comment: "Set is not applicable as a Set does not maintain ordering." — with the exception of sets that define an iteration order, such as `HashSet`, `TreeSet`, or any other set that implements [`SequencedSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/SequencedSet.html).

Answer (score 0):

ArrayList will probably be your best bet. You can iterate through it in the following manner:

```
for (ListIterator it = list.listIterator(list.size()); it.hasPrevious();) {
    Object value = it.previous();
}
```

A LinkedList will work but it will have more object creation overhead since you need to instantiate a Link for each element you store.